# Finite-index subgroups of dense additive subgroups of $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups, additive-combinatorics

Let $A$ be a dense additive subgroup of $\mathbb R$ and let $B\le A$ be a subgroup such that $[A:B]=r<\infty$. I wonder if we have that $B$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ as well.

My thoughts: Write $A=\bigsqcup_{i=1}^{r} (x_i+B)$. Suppose $B$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$, say $(a,b)\cap B=\varnothing$, I want to find an interval $(c,d)\cap A=\varnothing$. I feel like some additive combinatoris argument is needed here, but I don't know how.

Comment: In general if $G$ is a Hausdorff topological group, $H$, is a dense subgroup and $L$ a finite index subgroup of $H$, then the closure of $L$ is a closed (hence open) subgroup of finite index of $G$. And in $G=\mathbf{R}$, and more generally when $G$ is connected, the only open subgroup is $G$ itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, if $G\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a subgroup which is not dense, then G is discrete (i.e. $r\mathbb{Z}$ for some $r\in \mathbb{R}$).
To see this, consider the set $D=\{a-b\mid a,b\in G, a\neq b\}$.
We have $r\mathbb{Z}\subset G$ for every $r\in D$, so G being non-dense implies that $D$ has a positive infimum, i.e. $G$ is discrete.

Therefore, if $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a non-dense subgroup, then it cannot be of finite index in a dense subgroup.